# Keep reference of ViewChild in parent class

Tags: angular, viewchild

I want to access to my graph in my child component through @ViewChild, which is declared in my parent class. I don't want to redeclare a new variable for every child class.

Parent class:

```
import { Component, ViewChild} from '@angular/core';
import { BaseChartDirective } from 'ng2-charts';
import { LabelOptions } from '../labelOptions';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-graph',
  styleUrls: ['./graph.component.css']
})
export class GraphComponent {

  @ViewChild(BaseChartDirective) public chart: BaseChartDirective;
  //[.....some properties of a Graph.....]

  public setChart(data: any[], labels: string[]){
      this.chart.labels = labels;
      this.chart.datasets = data;
      this.update();
  }

}
```

Child class:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { GraphComponent } from '../../../shared/graph/graph.component';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-pie-graph',
  templateUrl: './pie-graph.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./pie-graph.component.css']
})
export class PieGraphComponent extends GraphComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(){
    super();
    this.setType("pie");
  }

  public chartHovered(e:any): void {
    console.log(e);
  }

  ngOnInit(){
    this.setType("pie");
    console.log(this.chart);
    this.setChart([234, 234, 234], ["a", "b", "c"]);
    //console.log(this.chart);
  }
}
```

The problem occurs when I try to access to the parent class' methods, it throws me undefined, in my case the problem is with `setChart`

Answer (score 0):

The `@ViewChild` queries are accessible only after the view is init. You need to move your code to `ngAfterViewInit`.

You also might run into some problems with decorators inheritance. Check out this [github issue](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/11606) for more info.

Comment: Thank you so much. Which parts of the code should I move?

Comment: You can access the `this.chart` only after the view is init (`ngAfterViewInit`).

Comment: `export class PieGraphComponent extends GraphComponent implements OnInit, AfterViewInit {

  ngAfterViewInit(){
    console.log(this.chart);
    //this.setChart([234, 234, 234], ["a", "b", "c"]);
  }`

No problem with this.chart, but with setChart